# How to prevent shutil.move from overwriting a file if it already exists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I'm using this `Python` code in `Windows`:

```
shutil.move(documents_dir + "\\" + file_name, documents_dir + "\\backup\\"
            + subdir_name + "\\" + file_name)
```

When this code is called more times, it overwrites the destination file. I would like to move the file
and if the destination already exists, to rename it

e.g. `file_name` = `foo.pdf`

and in `backup` folder will be `foo.pdf`, `foo(1).pdf`, `foo(2).pdf` etc. or similarly e.g. with dashes
`foo-1.pdf`, `foo-2.pdf` etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just check with `os.path.exists()` as you're going.

```
import os
import shutil

file_name = 'test.csv'
documents_dir = r'C:\BR\Test'
subdir_name = 'test'

# using os.path.join() makes your code easier to port to another OS
source = os.path.join(documents_dir, file_name)
dest = os.path.join(documents_dir, 'backup', subdir_name, file_name)

num = 0
# loop until we find a file that doesn't exist
while os.path.exists(dest):
    num += 1

    # use rfind to find your file extension if there is one
    period = file_name.rfind('.')
    # this ensures that it will work with files without extensions
    if period == -1:
        period = len(file_name)

    # create our new destination
    # we could extract the number and increment it
    # but this allows us to fill in the gaps if there are any
    # it has the added benefit of avoiding errors 
    # in file names like this "test(sometext).pdf"
    new_file = f'{file_name[:period]}({num}){file_name[period:]}'

    dest = os.path.join(documents_dir, 'backup', subdir_name, new_file)

shutil.move(source, dest)
```

Or since this is probably used in a loop you could just drop it into a function.

```
import os
import shutil

def get_next_file(file_name, dest_dir):
    dest = os.path.join(dest_dir, file_name)
    num = 0

    while os.path.exists(dest):
        num += 1

        period = file_name.rfind('.')
        if period == -1:
            period = len(file_name)

        new_file = f'{file_name[:period]}({num}){file_name[period:]}'

        dest = os.path.join(dest_dir, new_file)

    return dest

file_name = 'test.csv'
documents_dir = r'C:\BR\Test'
subdir_name = 'test'

source = os.path.join(documents_dir, file_name)

dest = get_next_file(file_name, os.path.join(documents_dir, 'backup', subdir_name))

shutil.move(source, dest)
```